# Change color of notification title (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin

That's my code and everything works fine.

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "NOTI_ID")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
```

The only problem is I can't change the color of the title (= "Hello World"). The last line `.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))` changes only the icon-color. I found nothing in the documentation and if you look at [those images](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#reply-action), you see the title have the same color as the icon. So I'm not sure if the error comes from me or my code missing something?

**EDIT**

With title I mean the app name. Sorry, it was my mistake. Not the contentTitle, but the name of the app. Check for example [those images](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#reply-action).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using this approach in Java:

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
builder.setContentTitle(HtmlCompat.fromHtml("<font color=\"" + color + "\">" + notificationTitle + "</font>", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I made a mistake. Check the question again

Comment: Not sure what you wanna do here, correct me if I'm wrong, you want your notification app name colored differently as your app icon?

Comment: No, the app name should have the same color as the app icon. I can change the color of the app icon, but the app name is still dark gray

Comment: This is the exact default behavior. The app name has the same color as app icon when you use `builder.setColor(int)`. What else is happening? Perhaps you're using a colored small icon instead of a solid white one, aren't you?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work. When I add for example `.setColor(255)`, the app icon changes the color, the name of the app is still dark gray.

Comment: Try your code with a new raw Android project see if changes anything. And use the new project default icons and settings, just your code (to determine the core culprit)

Comment: There are no changes. I fear it only works with a CustomContentView like [here](https://help.pushwoosh.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000787106-Colored-application-name-for-Android-notification).

Comment: Does it have the same behavior when you run it on a different device or emulator like an emulator with the latest Android version?

Comment: Yes, I'm currently this code and it's working: `NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif).setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.new_requests_from_club)).setLargeIcon(getConversationPicture(context, conversationId, club.getPicture(), true)) .setContentText(contentText).setAutoCancel(true).setOnlyAlertOnce(true).setColor(Color.RED);` which makes both app icon and name red.

Comment: Indeed it is
Can you send me your new raw project so I can check it out?

Comment: My goodness, I got it. It works on API 27. I created a new emulator with API 27 and finally it works... It seems the problem is with the API 28. The question is now why it doesn't work on API 28?

Comment: Nice. But my phone is currently running on 28 and it's working as expected! Have you checked it on a real device, cause as I said already this is the default behavior of Android apps

Comment: At the moment I haven't a device working on API 28, but it's okay. You say it works on your device with API 28, I'll trust you :) I'm very grateful for the generous and kind support from you, thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Can you please help me. I am also facing this issue and only the notification icon colour is getting changed. What is the way to change the app name's colour?