# Change Firebase notification title color - Android 9.0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to ensure a default Firebase notification icon and color are displayed when my app receives a Firebase notification. This is done like so:

1. In `onMessageReceived` function:

```java
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder =
  new NotificationCompat.Builder(
    mContext.getApplicationContext(),
    mContext.getString(R.string.notificationChannelID)
  )
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eb_logo)
  .setLargeIcon(
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
  )
  .setColor(Color.parseColor("#4dbeed"))
  .setContentTitle(title)
  .setContentText(content)
  .setAutoCancel(true)
  .setChannelId(channelID)
  .setPriority(channelImportance);
```

2. In the manifest `AndroidManifest.xml` file like so:

```xml
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/eb_logo" />

<!-- Notification details (colors etc.) for Firebase notifications. -->
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
  android:resource="@color/ebFirebaseNotificationColor" />
```

This works perfectly on Android 8.0. However, on Android 9.0 and above, the color of the title text remains the default grey despite the above changes.

I found one link: [Change color of notification title (Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56914743/change-color-of-notification-title-android-studio) that seems to hint at this.

Anyone else face this same issue? I have gone through the relevant firebase cloud messaging and android 9.0 changelogs and not found anything.

Any help on this is most welcom.

Comment: may I know, `android:resource="@drawable/eb_logo"` the size need to small ?

Comment: @Ticherhaz: im afraid i dont understand the question. Are you saying if the eb_logo needs to be small?

Comment: Yes, it need to be small or not?